# php, add trailing zeros if the number is integer

Tags: php

Simple maths:

```
  $a=$b/$c; echo $a;
```

if $b equals to 123.00  and $c equals to 1 then $a becomes 123.

If $b is 123.50, $c is 1, $a is 123.50. But in the former case , I want $a to be 123.00.

It is possible to test whether $a has any non-zero fraction part or not, and then add the trailing zeros as necessary.

But I am looking for php functions  to do the same thing. Possible?

**EDIT :**

What if I do not want the commas from `number_format` there ?

Comment: What about floor() and using number_format() for output?

Comment: in a table row , other numbers are decimal. So I want this number in decimal format too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert strings to numbers without losing decimals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677082/convert-strings-to-numbers-without-losing-decimals)

Comment: @visakhsujathan, the question you mentioned was asked just only 2 days ago whereas this question was asked several years ago!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use `sprintf("%0.2f",$a);`. [docs](http://php.net/sprintf)

Comment: @nickb how is that correct - http://codepad.viper-7.com/naZQVN ? Or I'm not seeing somth?

Comment: @ZoltanToth - From the OP: But in the former case , **I want $a to be 123.00.**

Comment: @nickb Sorry, my bad. I thought in the 1st case the OP wants just **123**, and in the 2nd - **123.00** (floored with decimals)

Answer (score 15):

Use the [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function. If you don't want comma separators, set all four parameters of the function like so (the thousands separator is the fourth parameter):

```
$number = number_format(1234, 2, '.', '');
```

Comment: The link to the function `number_format()` would be more helpful.

Comment: @Palladium, recognized as useful

Answer (score 4):

Yup, using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php function like this:

```
$a = 123;
$answer = number_format($a,"2");
echo $answer;
```