# Convert strings to numbers without losing decimals

Tags: php, string, parsing, numbers

I'm developing a map and I have to save this parameters on Parse database:

lat.: 20.6350 . Long: -103.5334

The problem is when i convert them into numbers, that function converts 20.6350 to 20.635. ¿What can I do in order tu preserve the last zero?

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11510733/3933332

Comment: They don't "lose" numbers/digits; they simply __display__ only the significant digits by default (and trailing zeroes aren't significant) unless you specify that they must be displayed with number_format() or sprint()

Comment: No, it didn't work Rizier123. I want to keep the original value. If the original value is 34.334200 i have to preserve that value. If is 343.99 the same.

Comment: You say "I want to keep the original value". The original value *is* 34.3342, as far as the double class is concerned. If you want additional digits stored, then what you want is outside the capability of a double value. Either you could store the information as a string, or you could store the number of significant digits along with each double. Nothing you can do to a double will make it remember how many zeroes you typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the sig figs and they will display properly.

```
$lat = "20.6350";
$lng = "-103.5334";

print number_format($lat, 4); // 4 sig figs
print number_format($lng, 4);
```

See http://php.net/number_format for additional formatting info

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments above, seems the string you're pulling varies in length, correct?

Why not just get the amount of sig figs after the decimal then use that as the second argument in `number_format()`? I'm sure there is a more appropriate way to handle, but this would work I believe.

```
// Calculate sig figs
$length = strlen($lng) - (stripos($lng, '.') + 1);
number_format($lng, $length);
```

or in one line

```
number_format($lng, strlen($lng) - (stripos($lng, '.') + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the numbers with four decimals in your database you could use the **Decimal** type. Under **length** you could enter **6,4** representing maximum of 6 digits in total and 4 digits behind the point.

If you want to display the number in PHP you could use the number_format() function

```
echo number_format($longitude, 4);
```